# Solving the Laplace equation in a rectangle, using the separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Suppose I have $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ on a region $R=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq\alpha,0\leq y\leq\beta\}$ with boundary conditions $f(0,y)=f(\alpha,y)=0$, $f(x,0)=g(x)$, and $f(x,\beta)=h(x)$. I considered a solution using the standard separation of PDEs:

$$f(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{Y''}{-Y}=-\lambda$$
$$Y(y)=k_1\cosh(\sqrt\lambda y)+k_2\sinh(\sqrt\lambda y)$$

But my solution for $Y(y)$ is always senseless, even if I change the sign on $\lambda$, because of the boundary value conditions. So I then considered trying to solve this as I would a non-homogeneous heat equation, where $f(x,y)=v(x)+w(x,y)$, but since I can't get a nice relation on $v_{xx}$ here given that it is not a steady-state, this approach gets me nothing.

What should I try now?

Comment: The PDE $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ is homogeneous, contrary to the title of your question. The boundary conditions are inhomogeneous, which is to be expected -- otherwise the solution would be identically zero.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the correction. That was a misunderstanding of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is right. Separated solutions will be $X_n(x)Y_n(y)$ where
$$X_n(x)=\sin \frac{\pi n}{\alpha}x,$$
from the homogeneous boundary conditions. Accordingly, 
$$Y_n(y)=A_n\cosh \frac{\pi n}{\alpha}y+B_n\sinh \frac{\pi n}{\alpha}y$$
It remains to make sure that $\sum X_n(x)Y_n(0)=g(x)$ and $\sum X_n(x)Y_n(\pi)=h(x)$. Begin with the first one: the equation 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin \frac{\pi n}{\alpha}x = g(x)
$$
determines all $A_n$ coefficients. Then, from 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(A_n\cosh \frac{\pi n \beta}{\alpha}+B_n\sinh \frac{\pi n \beta}{\alpha}\right) \sin \frac{\pi n}{\alpha}x = h(x)
$$
you determine $B_n$ coefficients.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier for me to consider $\sum C_n\exp(\frac{\pi n\beta}{\alpha})\sin(\frac{\pi nx}{\alpha})=h(x)$?

Comment: If you use exponential form instead of hyperbolic, you'll need $\exp(\dots)$ **and** $\exp(-\dots)$. This makes things more complicated: both kinds of terms are involved on both boundaries. Using hyperbolic functions helps because $\sinh 0 =0$, so $B_n$ get out of the way when you determine $A_n$.

Comment: I see now, I can determine $B_n$ because after distributing $\sin$ and using the functions' orthogonal properties, I have a Fourier coefficient equation. Thanks for your patient help.